# Can I get mac notification when a Tab has new output in iTerm2?

Tags: notifications, iterm

You know, iTerm2 will change the color of the tab to red or purple. But sometime when I run a long job in one tab, I have to check if it's done frequently. So.. can I get notification when there's new output in one tab? If so, how?

Comment: So the question was about "new output" or about "job done" in the tab? They are different... :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [Terminal Notifier](https://github.com/alloy/terminal-notifier/). Once installed run a command like this:

```
long-running-command && terminal-notifier -message "Done" -title "Done"
```

When `long-running-command` finishes you will get a notification.

Comment: Note the recommendation of using `;` instead of `&&` in [nwinkler response](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/145574/40482)

Comment: You can also do `long-process && terminal-notifier -message 'Done.' || terminal-notifier -message 'Error running long-process.'` for a different message on error.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only allows to track command completion, but not just new output when command is still running.

Answer (score 2):

To simplify the usage of the mentioned [Terminal Notifier](https://github.com/alloy/terminal-notifier/) tool, you should create an *alias* for it, including its parameters, so you don't have to type them all the time.

In your `.bashrc` file, add an alias like this:

```
alias termnot='terminal-notifier -message "Done" -title "Done"'
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
long-running-command ; termnot
```

BTW: I recommend using `;` to separate the commands instead of `&&`. `&&` is a conditional operator, it will only execute the second command if the first succeeded. So if your first command failed with a non-zero exit code, you will not receive a notification. Separating them with a semicolon will ensure that the second command is always run, regardless of the first command's exit code. More info here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100704/difference-between-executing-multiple-commands-with-and

One more thing: To install the Terminal Notifier tool, I recommend [Homebrew](http://brew.sh). Using Homebrew makes the installation as simple as

```
brew install terminal-notifier
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get a notification about *any* output the triggers may be used.

Go to **Session** > **Triggers** > **Add Trigger...**

[image: iTerm2 Add Trigger dialog]

Then enter `.*` (meaning **anything**) in **Regular Expression** box and choose **Post Notification...** in the **Action** dropdown. Enter the message you would like to see and press **OK**.

Now every time the new output appears in the console the notification in the Notifications center will be shown.

Later you can disable/reenable the trigger using **Session** > **Triggers** menu.